# Why does the file not be removed, which was created by tmpfile() of PHP, after the script ended?

Tags: php, temporary-files

The [PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) says, file created by tmpfile(), will automatically be removed when closed or when the script ends.

I have a script listed below:

```
    $file = tmpfile();
    $tmpFileName = array_search('uri', @array_flip(stream_get_meta_data($file)));
    file_put_contents($tmpFileName, 'test');
```

The /tmp/phpxxxx file still exists after after running the script.

If I append this line:

```
    fclose($file);
```

The temp file will be removed.

Why does this happend?
Is it because the script is not finshed? Or do I have a wrong configuration?

Comment: Fclose closes the file so I cannot be rewritten until you fopen again. Try unlink

Comment: @DarylGill - The docs explicitly state that `fclose()` will lead to the file being removed. Suren, if you want to ensure the file is removed, I wouldn't depend on PHP doing it for you as a side effect, I would always use the method that works each time.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks, so It's my misunderstanding of "script ends", or It's a bug of PHP?

Comment: I would think the docs indicate it should be removed once the file handle is closed (e.g., when the script execution is ended as the last opportunity). PHP may be hanging onto (or not closing) that handle. There may be some other things you're doing that may be blocking it somehow, like ending the script on `exit(0)` (just a guess, I don't know this will cause any issue) or something. My advice would be to call `fclose()` explicitly when you no longer need it; it's just a better practice to do.

Comment: Is there any permissions which restrict modifying inside that directory?

Comment: @DarylGill No. It's '/tmp' folder, and the script create the file, so I thinks the script has the permission to delete the file.

Comment: **thinks**.. I'd make sure, do not assume. Double check